# Make DataTable values as DropDown selected values in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a datatable with values and I need to assign them as default values to gridview dropdown list on button click event. I have tried writing the below code and it retains only the last row values. How can I retain all the rows?

Am I missing to add rows to the GridView?

**For example:** DataTable now has three rows and in GridView only the third row has the default values from DataTable and the first rows are empty.

```
DataTable dtValues = dtSource;                    
if (dtValues.Rows.Count > 0)
{
   for (int i = 1; i <= dtValues.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
       RadComboBox ID = (RadComboBox)gvGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("radID");
       RadComboBox Names = (RadComboBox)gvGrid.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("radName");
       ID.SelectedValue = dtValues.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString();
       Names.SelectedValue = dtValues.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Can anyone please correct me if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: On which _event_ this code is written? Can you share some more info? Your grid is binding fine? Is the issue only with dropdown?

Comment: @RahulSingh - Binding is fine. I've written this code in a button click event outside gridview.

Comment: what's your actual question?

Comment: @AsifAli72090 - I have a datatable with values and I need to assign them as default values to gridview dropdown list.

Comment: is Dropdownlist inside gridview?

Comment: @AsifAli72090 - Yes, the dropdown list is inside the gridview.

Comment: What about button? Is the button inside the grid? Also, what do you mean by _Default value_? Is your dropdown getting populated with values?

Comment: @RahulSingh - button is outside gridview. Default Value means `SelectedItem.Text`.

Answer (score 0):

You should need to use RowDataBound event of GridView as like below and populate it from DataTable as DataSource:

```
protected void gvGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // check if row is not in edit mode
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataTable dtValues = dtSource;

        // get dropdownlist from gridview
        var ddl = e.Row.FindControl("YourDropDown") as DropDownList;
        if (ddl != null)
        {
            ddl.DataSource = dtValues;
            ddl.DataTextField = "Name"; // add text to dropdownlist
            ddl.DataValueField = "ID"; // add value to dropdownlist
            ddl.DataBind();
            // add default selected value
            ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("----- Select a Value -----", "0"));
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** Don't forget to add OnRowDataBound event `gvGrid_RowDataBound` to your GridView.